# grow smaller 长小

Tags: translation

https://archive.org/stream/Asimovs_v13n13_1989-12-Mid/Asimovs_v13n13_1989-12-Mid_djvu.txt

> She watched the miniaturization procedure (she had seen it before) and
> saw Mike **grow smaller** and disappear.

Can I translate *grow smaller* to 长小？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I translate grow smaller to 长小？

The verb 'grow (长)' mostly mean 'become older or bigger'

Although 'grow smaller' literally means '长小', but 'grow' in 'grow smaller' actually means 'to develop into'. We translate 'grow smaller' to '变小' (become smaller) to avoid confusing 发展  (grow/ develop/ become) with 生长/ 成長 (grow)

长小 is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

It is better to translate as `变小`.

Answer (score 0):

no, we never say that. you can say "变小" or "变大" but "长小" is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Either 變小 /bian4 xiao3/ or 縮小 /suo1 xiao3/ (to shrink)。

*長小 is a bit of an oxymoron. 長大 or 長高 is OK, but never *長小 or *長矮。